# Data analysis question PYTHON about subsetting and selecting

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a question , i am actually learning data analysis with python , and i can't see the difference when we use these lines of code :

```
rice_consumption = food_consumption[food_consumption["food_category"]=="rice"]
```

for example we want to define rice_consumption, why here do we rewrite the dataframe "food_consumption" twice in the line, and when and why do we write it only once in another line of code, like that :

```
rice_consumption = food_consumption["food_category"]=="rice"
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
food_consumption["food_category"]=="rice"
```

Above line gives you a mask, which are composed of `True` or `False`. `food_consumption` with the mask as the argument can return you the items where mask value is `True`.